# C# No accessible extension method for override with specific type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

Forgive me if this has already been asked. I searched for it but couldn't find anything.

It seems like the compiler is getting confused by this code

```
public abstract class C1
{
    public int c1Prop;
}

public class C2 : C1
{
    public int c2Prop;
}

public abstract class P1
{
    public abstract void Run<T>(T c) where T : C1;
}

public class P2 : P1
{
    public override void Run<C2>(C2 c) 
    {
        c.c1Prop = 1; //Is recognized
        c.c2Prop = 2; //Is NOT recognized and is an error
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this wouldn't work at the function level. Since C2 extends C1 it's not violating the where check but the C2 type is still unrecognized in the overridden method.

For some background, I'm using a similar pattern in a Unity ScriptableObject which doesn't work well with generic classes so I'm not able to move the generic type up to the class level. Moving it up there does seem to fix the problem though.

Another potential workaround I came up with is to get rid of the generic method all together in favor of casting. That doesn't seem as expressive as a generic though. Also casting c in several places throughout the Run method would get annoying.

Comment: Naming your generic type argument `C2` does not relate it to any type having the same name. Your base class declares that it supports a `Run(C1)` call. A derived class cannot take that away. The right way to solve this depends on why you have the base class. You could make it a generic base class if you *just* want to avoid code duplication. Can you provide more info on whether that'll work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `void Run<C2>(C2 c)` you are saying that `C2` is a *generic type*, it's *not* the concrete type `C2`. To make this clearer, change `C2` to `T`:

```
public override void Run<T>(T c)
{
    c.c1Prop = 1; //Is recognized
    c.c2Prop = 2; //Is NOT recognized and is an error
}
```

The reason you can access `c1Prop` is the type constraint `where T : C1` earlier on in the hierarchy.

One way round this would be to make `P1` itself generic:

```
public abstract class P1<T> where T : C1
{
    public abstract void Run(T c);
}
```

Which makes `P2` look like this:

```
public class P2 : P1<C2>
{
    public override void Run(C2 c)
    {
        c.c1Prop = 1;
        c.c2Prop = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, yeah I hadn't considered that I was trolling myself by naming the generic method type the same as my class. Thanks for clearing it up for me.

Answer (score 1):

The initial cause of confusion is that within your `Run` override, `C2` is a **type parameter** - it *isn't* the class called `C2`. It's helpful to make that clear by leaving it as `T` in the declaration of the overriding method:

```
public class P2 : P1
{
    // Changed type parameter name from C2 to T for clarity
    public override void Run<T>(T c) 
    {
        c.c1Prop = 1;
        c.c2Prop = 2;
    }
}
```

That is absolutely equivalent code, but it's clearer what's going on.

Now `T` is constrained with `where T : C1` which is how `c.c1Prop` works - but it's *entirely feasible* that `c` will not be a `C2`. For example, I could write:

```
class OtherC1 : C1 {}

P2 p2 = new P2();
p2.Run(new OtherC1());
```

That clearly can't work with your current code - there's no `c2Prop` in `OtherC1`.

It sounds like you may want `P1` to be generic rather than the `Run` method. You could have:

```
public abstract class P1<T> where T : C1
{
    public abstract void Run(T c);
}

public class P2 : P1<C2>
{
    public override void Run(C2 c) 
    {
        c.c1Prop = 1; //Is recognized
        c.c2Prop = 2; //Is NOT recognized and is an error
    }
}
```

That will then compile, and all code will know that you can *only* provide a `C2` (or more derived class) to `P2.Run`. So our earlier example with `OtherC1` won't compile any more (which is what we'd want).

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature states that method should be generic and can't override it only for some concrete type, you can do the following:

```
    public class P2 : P1
    {
        public override void Run<T>(T c)
        {
            c.c1Prop = 1; //Is recognized since you have where T : C1 clause
            var c2 = c as C2;
            if (c2 != null)
            {
                c2.c2Prop = 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While i support @DavidG's approach, if you don't want to utilize a generic declaration on your class, you can use this approach

```
public interface IC1
{
    int prop1 { get; set; }
}

public interface IC2
{
    int prop2 { get; set; }
}

public abstract class C1 : IC1
{
    #region Implementation of IC1

    public int prop1 { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class C2 : C1, IC2
{
    #region Implementation of IC2

    public int prop2 { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public abstract class P1
{
    public abstract void Run<T>(T c) where T : IC1, IC2;
}

public class P2 : P1
{
    public override void Run<T>(T c)
    {
        c.prop1 = 1; 
        c.prop2 = 2; 
    }
}
```